# Finding a limit including an improper integral: $\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡ \int_0^{\sqrt n} \left({1-\frac{x^2}{n}}\right)^n\,dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

I was given a task to calculate that limit, though I'm having trouble with it..
I thought about that fact that $(1-x^2/n)^n$ converges to $e^{-x^2}$ and about switching limit and integral when the convergence is uniform, though I can't really get it done properly.
The limit is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡ \int_0^{\sqrt n} \left({1-\frac{x^2}{n}}\right)^n\,dx$$

Any help would be truely appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm dealing with improper integrals right now and with function series (Pointwise/uniform convergences) etc.. Calculus II

Comment: The sequence is monotonically increasing. Does that give you an idea how to proceed?

Comment: Do you mean dini's theorem?

Comment: In part. The monotonicity yields the existence of the limit, $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx$ gives an upper bound. Then Dini's theorem can be used to deduce that the limit is $\geqslant \int_0^a e^{-x^2}\,dx$ for every $a \in [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Understood, thank you very much!